# Context Processor for Django Site

Tags: python, django, django-context

I'm builing a wedding website creator (no judgement please).

Almost every view needs to call a `Wedding.objects.get(id=wedding_id)` and then pass it to the template as part of the variables.

Seems like this is a good use for a custom context processor. Wondering what the best way to create a context processor that would read the URL and if there was a wedding ID, include a wedding object in the template. If there wasn't a wedding ID, then wedding=None in the template.

Comment: have you tried to create the context processor yet? Sounds like you just described exactly what you would do. Create the function that reads the url and returns a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would make sure you really need this for almost every request, since you would be coding in an explicit query to each request. A `get` query is immediate as opposed to a lazy `filter`. If you wanted to make it more lazy you could wrap the get in a small "get_wedding" wrapper, or use a `filter` and just grab it from the list...

```
def add_wedding_context(request):
    id_ = request.GET.get('wedding_id', None)
    wedding = None
    if id_ is not None:
        try:
            wedding = Wedding.objects.get(id=id_)
        except Wedding.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return {'wedding':wedding}
```

If you want to try a lazy approach, so that the query only gets run if you actually use the object, you can wrap it in a lazy object:

```
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
from functools import partial

def get_wedd_or_none(id_):
    try:
        return Wedding.objects.get(id=id_)
    except Wedding.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def add_wedding_context(request):
    id_ = request.GET.get('wedding_id', None)
    if id_ is not None:
        lazy = SimpleLazyObject(partial(get_wedd_or_none, id_))
        return {'wedding': lazy}
    else:
        return {'wedding': None}
```

Comment: Right now the wedding ID is just part of the URL conf, not a GET variable. so it's http://weddingsite.com/wedding_id/photos. How would I alter your add_wedding_context to account for that?

Comment: Then you would have to use the other approach on here that uses a regular expression to parse out the wedding ID. Be aware that if your url pattern changes you will need to remember to maintain the regex. To be honest, a context manager is inappropriate for this because it removes the ability for you to handle error states with the wedding id in your views. What if they dont have permission? Or it doesnt exist? I would just perform the neccessary logic in the view and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def add_wedding_ring(request):
  if re.match('.*/id=.*',request.get_full_path()):
     return {'wid':Wedding.objects.get(id=wedding_id)}
  return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Brenden why context processor? If you use `Django>=1.3` then you can just use class based view like

```
class ViewWedding(DetailView):
  model = Wedding
  pk_url_kwarg = 'wedding_id'
  template_name = 'you-template.html'
  context_object_name = 'wedding'
```

Does it worth to have one more context processor instead of passing `wedding` instance from a view by the way I think its more flexible and preferable way to context_processor?

Thanks,

Sultan